# Excel vba insufficient memory while creating userform

Tags: excel, vba, memory

I'm creating a userform in Excel that save data in multiple sheet. Everything work fine with my older version (2866 lines of code, 960 textbox, 500+ labels, a maximum entry of 960 column by 100,000 row).

I tried to add 200 text box for a new type of data and when I tried to add lines of code, I had a message saying "insufficient memory" which is strange because the userform is not actualy running.

Does this means that I'm pushing VBA too far? What can I do to clear/allow more memory?

Before you tell me that it's a stupid idea to make a big database application out of Excel, I want to tell you that I know it's a bad idea and I told my boss too but he made it clear that it has to be on Excel (Not python, java, C#, C++ or anything else that could have been beter and we don't have any database like oracle or sqlite lmao).

Thank you all for your time - Vincent

****EDIT
Context of this application: by opening this excel you have to login with a home made login userform (The account define the amount of data that you can see or use). Then the main userform will apear on the "Menu" page. From there, you can navigate to see your client with a lot of information on them, then you can create/modify a client witch is a page with all the textbox. You can also go to your inventory witch contains all treatment on crop field (from now to past 6 years), weeds on crop field (max 50 species, size of plant, number of plant, ...) and type of field (soil, crop, gps location,...) for every field of each client. You also have more pages with your account information (change password, notes, ...) and one with administrator access like printing datas, accessing all data, creating/manging user and their right in the userform (User, Admin, Prog).

Like I said it's a huge application and I can only use Excel...

Comment: I can't even comprehend having over 1000 text boxes. Why...? Are they split between separate user forms? Or are you rebuilding an excel sheet inside a userform by replacing cells with text boxes?

Comment: Actually someone who needs over 1000 controls does clearly something wrong. I would say clearly a [X/Y-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You ask for a solution for X but your issue is Y. Please [edit] and give some background information. A screenshot of that userform might help too.

Comment: My suggestion is that you change methods and ditch the userform idea. Make an excel sheet into the data entry page, and limit where the user can enter data using sheet protection. Excel is optimized to handle data on a sheet, but not large data in a userform.

Comment: Or use more efficient controls like listbox or listview can help too. Higly depends on how your actual userform looks like I would say.

Comment: @Toddleson /1/ Almost rebuilding an excel because people where making mistake or deleting pages which was anoying to get back. /2/ Tried in my first version but people make mistake and deleted pages.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ /1/ see my edit /2/ I use listbox and combobox but I only writed textbox to reduce the text length.

Comment: So first `home made login userform` is not secure and everyone who has the Excel file can always easily view **all** the data that is in it (you cannot make it secure with VBA, that is fact). Besides that this is **clearly** a database usecase and you are off the limits of Excel. Switch at least to Access better to some kind of SQL. I'm pretty sure this has gone way off limits.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ That's what I also think but that is not the point, I want to know if the amount of things in my userform cause the insufficient memory?

Comment: @VincentCoulombe Impossible to say that for sure but if you want an opinion: Yes, very high probability that you are off limits now. I mean there is a reason why databases exist. They were desinged to handle a lot of data in a more efficient way. Excel was desinged to calculate with formulas in sheets, later they added VBA and userforms to be able to build small tools. Excel was never desinged to handle heavy data nor was it desinged to perform with heavy data in VBA and userforms. So very likely you scratched the edged here.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thanks that is what I thought, I'll try again to go on python and oracle, but it will probably end up in two excel files with that way to think...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all of you for your answers. I found out that I pushed too far for Excel by exceeding the memory limits of VBA projects by adding and incredible amount of labels, text/combo/list-box and more on this web site ([https://www.decisionmodels.com/memlimitsc.htm#:~:text=VBA%20Memory%20Limits,of%20about%204GB%20for%20VBA.](https://www.decisionmodels.com/memlimitsc.htm#:%7E:text=VBA%20Memory%20Limits,of%20about%204GB%20for%20VBA.))

Take care - Vincent